# Usage of asterisk(*) before new(dynamic allocation) in c++

Tags: c++

```
 board *gameBoard = new board(givenX,givenY,givenMineCount);
```

I know that the above statement declares an object pointer that points to board.

But I'm wondering what the statement below means.

```
 board gameBoard = *new board(givenX,givenY,givenMineCount);
```

Comment: It means the programmer is a novice and should be taught never EVER to do that.

Comment: But what exactly does it mean?

Comment: It's the memory leak operator.

Comment: I really don't understand the down-voters... This is a legitimate question.. I need to read and understand code, and the code use that ***new** thing, So I can't ask?!?! Thanks @TejaReddy for your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to c++, but I think extra details are missing here for beginners like me and like **the asker**.

***Note: This answer contains details for newbies like me.. advanced c++ developers may find this post somewhat confusing!***

***Lazy?*** tl;dr at the end

Does always creating and object with `*new` creates two copies of objects? (one will never ever be deleted)

Lets check this out:

As explained by others, the `*new` is just a shortcut to new in one statement and then dereference it with the asterisk operator (*)

Consider the following struct that holds a single number:

```
struct myStruct
{
public:
    myStruct() { innerNumber = 0; }
    myStruct(uint16_t num) {
        innerNumber = num;
    }

    uint16_t innerNumber;
};
```

Lets create a SINGLE object, and dereference it MULTIPLE times:

```
myStruct* obj = new myStruct();

myStruct obj1 = *obj;
myStruct obj2 = *obj;
myStruct obj3 = *obj;

obj1.innerNumber = 1;
obj2.innerNumber = 2;
obj3.innerNumber = 3;

printf("%d-%d-%d\n", obj1.innerNumber, obj2.innerNumber, obj3.innerNumber);
```

> prints: **1-2-3**
>
> Pretty cool =] (and dangerous)

---

So, if we get it correctly, it is ALWAYS a bad idea to use `*new` as already mentioned here, it will always cause a memory leak!!

lets see it in action:

```
while (true) {
    myStruct& inner = *new myStruct();
    delete &inner;
}
```

That code should:

1. enter an infinite while loop
2. allocate a new myStruct object
3. dereference it (**causing it to be copied!**)
4. delete **the copy** only

Or in shortly: **A MEMORY LEAK**

Well, I'm running this, and the memory isn't increasing!

> `*new` is **GOOD** when creating a reference. You can see that I defined
>   a ref type by the & operator (`myStruct& inner`)

---

Another problem that may arise (and is general for references) is that:

```
// Create a reference
myStruct& inner = *new myStruct();
inner.innerNumber = 0;

// WHAT WILL HAPPEN HERE?
myStruct whatAmI1 = inner;
myStruct whatAmI2 = inner;

whatAmI1.innerNumber = 1;
whatAmI2.innerNumber = 2;

printf("Original: %d   Copies: %d-%d\n", inner.innerNumber, whatAmI1.innerNumber, whatAmI2.innerNumber);
```

> prints: **Original: 0   Copies: 1-2**
>
> dangerous!

---

### TL;DR

- `*new` is **bad** for creating value types
- `*new` is **good** for creating reference type
- **Be careful** when assigning a reference type to a value variable, it
  makes a copy

Comment: Solid answer. If targeting new coders, you might want to add a sentence about not using new at all in modern C++, and using smart pointers instead.

Comment: First thing, dereferencing a pointer on itself does not cause any copy. Second, I would never ever recommend to create references like that. It is the best way to confuse everything. It's just making less clear that this reference refers to a object allocated on the heap and thus needs to be deleted. It's better to stick with `int * a = new int(5); delete a;` if we really need a dynamic allocation (not mentioning that smart pointers would be the real thing to do anyway). So @nick I would not call this a _"solid answer"_ since it kind of encourages people to do things which are bad IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

In both statements the "new" keyword returns a pointer to the object you are allocating. The reason the second statement works is because if you put a * before a pointer you dereference that pointer which, in simple terms, gives you the object the pointer is pointing to. But as Mooing Duck said if you don't understand this you should avoid the new keyword all together.

Edit: to answer what it means? it means you allocate a board object then dereference it and save a new copy in your variable gameBoard. Essentially giving you two copies of the Board object.

Comment: It is in fact not my code. I'm doing a vulnerability analysis on someone else's code.

Comment: If you actually do not understand what the above does I don't know why you would do a vulnerability analysis on someones code. Generally thats a lot of work and a lot of advanced knowledge to pick out code vulnerabilities.

Comment: @TejaReddy: it's a memory leak. If the attacker can cause that to trigger often, he can run the process or machine out of memory causing it to crash.

Comment: Actually, between `make_unique`, `make_shared`, and a handful of more obscure things, you shouldn't ever use `new` at all even as an *experienced* programmer.

Comment: @o11c very true but I didn't think OP was at the experience level that differentiating that far would make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

`new board(givenX,givenY,givenMineCount);` in a nutshell, performs two things: creates a `board` object in memory and returns the address where it was created.

In your second statement, `gameBoard` is a stack variable that holds a `board` object. As I mentioned before, the `new` returns an address and by using the `*` operator, you're basically "interpreting" (the actual technical term is dereferencing) the address as a board. That said, doing this seems to be making a copy and assigning it to `boardGame` and leave lingering in memory what was created with `new`.