# How to delete memory for object created by *new

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have question regarding memory management in c++
In below example is there any memory leakage. If so how to clear memory.
Also defining int by * new is the only option to use and not int num = 25;

```
int main()
{
  for(int i = 0;i < 200;i++)
  {
    int num = * new int(25);
  }
```

I tried many ways but delete and free does not work

Comment: `*new` is called the memory leak operator. It is an aberration.

Comment: you need to store the value returned by new in a pointer

Comment: [r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly)

Comment: new of one integer is overkill anyway, what are you trying to do?

Comment: and using new is not the "only option to use" - it is the very last one

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes it is!

Comment: Niraj where are you learning C++ from? Maybe your source is outdated and still showing a lot of code with new/delete in it. Or have you leared this in a datastructures class? (datastructure classes will teach about datastructures using C++, but they will not teach proper/current C++)

Comment: @Mat: I've never seen this construct (and for good reason by the sound of it). Is this a known antipattern ? Any idea how to google for this ? 

Edit: Ah, found something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699180/usage-of-asterisk-before-newdynamic-allocation-in-c
This might be a dupe for that, actually.

Comment: Good explanations here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks @nick

Comment: @nick it is not an antipattern, it is a gross programming error. However the name *memory leak operator* precisely describes what happens here, that is to lose the pointer without storing it as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a case of the "teacher using terrible code to illustrate a point" syndrome, and you're expected to do `int& num = *new int(25); delete &num;` which, despite being valid, nobody would ever do in the real world.

Comment: why is `int num = 25;` not an option? In this case `int num = 25;` is memory managment done the right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OP: Also defining int by * new is the only option to use and not int num = 25;

No, in `C++` you have different ways of create new data. In short, you can create new data automatically, dynamically or statically.

##### `automatic storage duration`

```
A a obj;
```

Here you're creating an object with *automatic storage duration*, this means, the object will be cleaned up when it goes out of scope. This object is created directly in the current active `stack frame`, so is directly accesible via identifier.

##### `dynamic storage duration`

Dynamic storaged objects are created with the `new` operator. This objects are stored on the `heap`, which is an unordered (mostly) region of memory reserved to handle `heap allocations`. The `heap` isn't able to talk with the stack regions directly, but we can communicate the `stack` and the `heap` program's data with pointers.

The `new` operator called in front on an object constructor, will perform a `heap` allocation, placing the value in some place of the `heap` and returning a `pointer` to the memory address where the value resides, available in the active stack.

```
A* a obj = new A();
```

Here, we are adquiring a resource that, as `C++` developers, we must take care. So, when we end with our `a` object, we must tell the compiler that we finished with it and that piece of memory should be released or freed. We acomplish this in `C++` with the `delete` keyword.

```
A* a obj = new A();

/* snip */

delete a;
```

If we don't delete the dynamically constructed resource, we will produce a memory leak. This is, we lose the access (the returned pointer) to the resource, and we can't no longer reach it. So, that resource w'd be using memory until the `OS` claim by itself that memory (and that's could also not happen), being in a *undefined behaviour* state, potentially leading to crashes and other things.

##### `static storage duration`

The storage for the object is allocated when the program begins and deallocated when the program ends. Only one instance of the object exists. All objects declared at namespace scope (including global namespace) have this storage duration, plus those declared with static or extern

##### `thread storage duration`

The storage for the object is allocated when the thread begins and deallocated when the thread ends. Each thread has its own instance of the object. Only objects declared thread_local have this storage duration. thread_local can appear together with static or extern to adjust linkage.

### What's wrong with your code snippet?

```
int num = * new int(25);
```

You are dynamically initializing a variable with a value. This is because you are inmediatly `dereferencing` the pointer that the `new` operator returns, losing your access to the `heap` allocated variable. `delete` won't work, because you need a pointer type to apply the operator over it, and delete the resource beyond the pointer, that will be the result of the expression `new int (25)`. This will return an `int*` that will store the address of the dynamically initialized integer.

Probably, you're looking for something like:

```
for(int i = 0;i < 200;i++)
{
   int* num = new int(25);
   /* snip */
   delete num;
}
```

#### TL;DR

Your deferencing, or following the pointer to the memory address that the `new` keyword applied on the `int` constructor returns to you, and then saving the value (not the pointer!) in the `int num` variable, losing the access to the heap allocated data, and causing a *memory leak*

Answer (score 1):

> is there any memory leakage

Yes. You created an `int` via `new` and immediately loose any reference to the pointer.

> If so how to clear memory

You cant. `num` is just holds a copy of the value. You have no way to `delete` the actual `int` that was dynamically allocated.

> Also defining int by * new is the only option to use and not int num = 25;

That makes no sense. Maybe there are things you didn't mention (odd requirements, weird assignment, or similar), but based on what you say, this is the correct way of "managing the memory":

```
for(int i = 0;i < 200;i++)
{
   int num = 25;
}
```

`num` has automatic storage duration. Its memory will be freed when it goes out of scope.

> I tried many ways but delete and free does not work

For `delete` you need the pointer returned by `new`. You don't have that. Mixing `free` with `new` is wrong.